# <feature> tag issue with webworks for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, config, blackberry-webworks

I have a an application for Blackberry Webworks that contains a menu entry in one screen. I have added the `blackberry.ui.menu` feature to the config.xml and it works great. The issue comes when I then add the feature `blackberry.ui.dialog`. The menu entry doesn't show anymore. Adding other features different from dialog doesn't break it.

Why is this happening? How can I keep my menu entry and also use the dialog feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the feature element(s) below in your configuration document:

Check the following link for help
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/blackberry.ui.dialog.html

Comment: Declaring only the `blackberry.ui.menu` feature works great, if I declare the `blackberry.ui.dialog` alongside the menu it breaks the menu.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20771/BB_Widget_SDK_1.5_Known_Issues_1316662_11.jsp

Comment: It is a known issue you can't create menus and dialogs at the same time??? Blackberry always amuses me.